# Keep transparency when saving svg animation to apng sequence

Tags: png, svg, transparency, vector-graphics, animation

Is there a way to do this on Windows? I tried `ImageMagick` with no luck. Some programs work for static `svg` files, but I haven't found a way to do this for `svg` animations.

I have an animation file in `svg` format. I would like to convert it to an `apng` sequence with transparency. I don't know how to be more specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.